# Render iframe without content and apply font Name and size using exec command. font name and size not apply before mouse click when type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, exec

Render iframe without content and apply a font Name and size using exec command when document load. In document ready function, I set a iframe focus then applied a font name and font size using Exec command.

After render, without click an iframe if i type a content in iframe, fontname and size are applied.
    But when i click an iframe then type any content the font name and size are not applied.

Please refer to the below code snippet:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Focus</title>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.globalize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <iframe id="iframeResult" width="100%" height="300px"  name="iframe_a"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            // declaration
            $($("#iframeResult").contents()[0].body).attr({"contenteditable":true,"autocorrect":"off"});
            $("#iframeResult").contents()[0].execCommand("fontSize", false, "2");
            $("#iframeResult").contents()[0].execCommand("fontName", false, "Arial");

       });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```